# Nodejs - Mocha: Rewire a parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a parent class like this:

```
'use strict';
class Test{
  constructor(){

  }

  my_method(){
    //some stuff here....
  }
}


module.exports = Test;
```

And a child class like this:

```
'use strict';
var Test = require('./test');

class ChildClass extends Test{

  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  some_other_method(){
    //some code....

    //
    this.my_method();

    //more code...
  }

}
module.exports = ChildClass;
```

In my tests, I'm trying to rewire the parent class method ('my_method'). Like this:

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
var Child = rewire('./child_class');
var Parent = rewire('./test');

describe("Test", function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    this.some_other_func = () =>{
      console.log('Do nothing...');
      return;
    };


    Parent.__set__('my_method', this.some_other_func);
    Child.__set__('Test', Parent);
  });

  it("some test....",() => {
    var child = new Child();
    child.some_other_method();
    //test stuff...

  });
});
```

But it's not working.
It's my first time using rewire with mocha, am I doing something wrong?